# C++: specializing member requires template<> syntax

Tags: c++, templates, definition, template-specialization, explicit-specialization

I am trying the following...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Singleton
{
private:
    class InstPtr
    {
    public:
        InstPtr() : m_ptr(0) {}
        ~InstPtr() { delete m_ptr; }
        T* get() { return m_ptr; }
        void set(T* p)
        {
            if (p != 0)
            {
                delete m_ptr;
                m_ptr = p;
            }
        }
    private:
        T* m_ptr;
    };

    static InstPtr ptr;
    Singleton();
    Singleton(const Singleton&);
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);

public:
    static T* instance()
    {
        if (ptr.get() == 0)
        {
            ptr.set(new T());
        }
        return ptr.get();
    }
};

class ABC
{
public:
    ABC() {}
    void print(void) { cout << "Hello World" << endl; }
};
```

When I am trying to do the following in visual studio, it works fine.. But when I compile using g++, it fails with `specializing member ‘Singleton<ABC>::ptr’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax`. What I am missing here?

```
#define ABCD (*(Singleton<ABC>::instance()))
template<> Singleton<ABC>::InstPtr Singleton<ABC>::ptr;
Singleton<ABC>::InstPtr Singleton<ABC>::ptr;

int main(void)
{
    ABCD.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cannot reproduce, I also get an error with msvc: https://godbolt.org/z/ccdEfza5q

Comment: why do you repeat `Singleton<ABC>::InstPtr Singleton<ABC>::ptr;` twice ?

Comment: You might look at Meyers's Singleton.

Comment: why do I get  undefined reference to `Singleton<ABC>::ptr'

Comment: Why one would write such complex code for a pattern that is not recommanded anymore and when one can make a singleton is far less code than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Singleton<ABC>::InstPtr Singleton<ABC>::ptr;
```

should be used for defining the `static` member of a explicitly specialized class template, e.g.

```
template<class T>
class Singleton
{
    ...
};

// explicit specialization
template<>
class Singleton<ABC>
{
private:
    class InstPtr
    {
        ...
    };

    static InstPtr ptr;
    
    ...
};

Singleton<ABC>::InstPtr Singleton<ABC>::ptr; // definition of the static member
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/71bJG115nRBcGguG)

---

And, the [explicit specialization of a `static` data member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) like

```
template<> Singleton<ABC>::InstPtr Singleton<ABC>::ptr;
```

is a declaration, but not a definition.

You need to specify initializer for it, e.g.

```
template<> Singleton<ABC>::InstPtr Singleton<ABC>::ptr{}; // definition of the static member
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3MTEsn8SKeTSV9Ge)

> An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template is a
> definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it
> is a declaration. These definitions must use braces for default
> initialization:
>
> ```
> template<> X Q<int>::x; // declaration of a static member
> template<> X Q<int>::x (); // error: function declaration
> template<> X Q<int>::x {}; // definition of a default-initialized static member
> ```